# This relative module was not found: * ./src/main.js in multi ./src/main.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, build

**npm run build** error!

I try all solutions for this problem but still not able to solve this. Many times i reinstall npm but not get proper solution **(Laravel 8 and Vue js)** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjskG.png)

### My package.json Code

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@webpack-cli/init": "^1.1.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.2.8",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^5.28.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: run this command `npm install -g @vue/cli` or `update -g @vue/cli`

Comment: Tried both the commands and still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I created a src folder(inside root) with a blank main.js file and it worked for me: reference is [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/439#issuecomment-496925301)